# Check notification balloons from other programs

Tags: c#, notifyicon, balloon-tip

I want to check notification balloons from all other running programs and keep records to look after with my C# program. How can I do that?

in this case
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vu9m.png)
I want to keep log of "Hello" and "This is a balloon tip!".

Comment: This is one of those things that Microsoft doesn't want you to be doing. In general the notification system is intended to be isolated from other programs. It helps to prevent adware, spyware and other malware from reading your notifications (from example from mail, social media, etc...), altering them for phishing (for example with fake offers), or blocking them (for example those from your antivirus). See [How do you intercept taskbar notification balloons?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131212-00/?p=2393/)

Comment: Raymond talks about why balloon tips should not be intercepted and changed by third parties, and he's right. He tacitly agrees that reading the tips for accessibility is a legitimate purpose, but doesn't explain how to do that. One of the reader comments suggests hooking `Shell_NotifyIcon`, which is the obvious approach. It's messy, hard to get right and not something you want to be doing in C#, though (and of course, also allows the bad stuff).

Comment: Didn't expect could be that hard. Thank you for information...